# Was ist der Unterschiede zwischen den Wörtern »Fähigkeit« und »Fertigkeit«?

Tags: meaning, difference

Die Wörter *Fähigkeiten* und *Fertigkeiten* bedeuten dasselbe und könnten als *skills* übersetzt werden. Sind diese Wörter Synonyme oder gibt es feinsinnige Unterschiede?

Comment: Das ist eine durchaus interessante Frage. Eine umfassende Auswertung der Belege wäre wünschenswert. Ich komme bereits auf über 2 Seiten Geschwafel und hab noch nicht mal richtig angefangen. Daher betrachte ich die Frage als zu undetailiert oder wahlweise opinion based (so @guidot bspw. "Um einen Aspekt der Definition von DWDS herauszuheben"). Die übliche Frage ist, was hast du im Wörterbuch gefunden. Eine einfache Übersetzung auf Englisch genügt dafür nicht, schließlich ist die Bedeutungsspanne des englischen Begriffs hier kein Thema. Dafür ist der Synonym-Begriff *zu weit*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um einen Aspekt der Definition von DWDS herauszuheben:

> Fertigkeit: durch Übung erworbene Gewandtheit, Geschicklichkeit im Ausführen bestimmter Tätigkeiten

Das heißt es handelt sich um eine *erlernte* Fähigkeit, die durch zusätzliche Übung auch verbessert werden kann. Eine gebräuchliche Zusammensetzung ist *Fingerfertigkeit*, die etwa beim Bedienen eines Musikinstruments oder beim Vorführen von Zaubertricks hilft.

Die *Fähigkeit*, beispielsweise Farbensehen (im Gegensatz zu Farbenblindheit) oder das *absolute Gehör*, hat man entweder, oder sie ist auch mit viel Mühe nicht zu erlangen.

Answer (score 3):

Die beiden Begriffe sind sehr ähnlich. Eine "Fähigkeit" ist allgemeiner und meint generell die Eigenschaft, zu etwas im Stande zu sein.

Eine "Fertigkeit" hat eine Reihe von zusätzlichen Konnotationen:

- Es geht um die Fähigkeit eines Menschen ("Fähigkeiten" allgemein können z. B. auch Geräte haben).
- Es geht um eine erworbene, erlernte oder antrainierte, nicht um eine angeborene Fähigkeit.
- Die Fähigkeit ist eher im körperlichen oder handwerklichen Bereich angesiedelt (wobei es hier relativ viele Ausnahmen gibt).
- Die Fähigkeit ist eher positiv bewertet.

Diese Punkte müssen nicht in jedem Fall, in dem "Fertigkeit" verwendet wird, alle in vollem Umfang zutreffen, aber sie beschreiben den Begriff mMn recht gut. "Fertigkeit" klingt außerdem im zeitgenössischen Deutsch bereits etwas altbacken.